# sed/awk: adding missed patterns to the string

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am working with text files containing somewhere a string

```
ligand_types A C Cl NA OA N SA HD    # ligand atom types
```

I need to check the patterns in the string: A C Cl NA OA N SA HD and in the case of the absence add to the end the missed "SA" and/or "HD".

Sample input:

```
ligand_types A C Cl NA OA N HD       # ligand atom types
ligand_types A C NA OA N SA          # ligand atom types
ligand_types A C Cl NA OA N          # ligand atom types
```

Expected output:

```
ligand_types A C Cl NA OA N HD SA    # ligand atom types
ligand_types A C NA OA N SA HD       # ligand atom types
ligand_types A C Cl NA OA N HD SA    # ligand atom types
```

May you suggest me sed or awk solution for this task?

For example using SED it may be:

```
sed -i 's/old-string/new-string-with-additional-patterns/g' my_file
```

Comment: either is fine, but i'd skip the -i flag cuz you don't want buggy code to overwrite ur original input file. if u insist on -i flag, then add in the extension suffix for the auto backup copy. you can always delete it later.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to just replace whatever is after `GPF> ligand_types ` with `A C Cl NA OA N SA HD` ?

Comment: hey, thanks for the idea! In fact, technically the strings may be slightly different so I would prefer to keep them original just checking whether the HD or SA patterns are present and them add them in the end in the case of the absence!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** adding support for end-of-line comments

Here's an `awk` idea:

```bash
awk -v types="SA HD" '
    BEGIN {
        typesCount = split(types,typesArr)
    }
    /^ligand_types / {

        if (i = index($0,"#")) {
            comment = substr($0,i)
            $0 = substr($0,1,i-1)
        } else
            comment = ""

        for (i = 1; i <= typesCount; i++)
            typesHash[typesArr[i]]

        for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++)
            delete typesHash[$i]

        for (t in typesHash)
            $(NF+1) = t

        if (comment)
            $(NF+1) = comment
    }
    1
' my_file > my_file.new
```

With your examples:

```
ligand_types A C Cl NA OA N SA HD    # ligand atom types
ligand_types A C Cl NA OA N SA HD # ligand atom types

ligand_types A C Cl NA OA N HD       # ligand atom types
ligand_types A C Cl NA OA N HD SA # ligand atom types

ligand_types A C NA OA N SA          # ligand atom types
ligand_types A C NA OA N SA HD # ligand atom types

ligand_types A C Cl NA OA N          # ligand atom types
ligand_types A C Cl NA OA N HD SA # ligand atom types
```

Comment: Many thanks for this sollution! sorry, actually I have a typo in the format of the search string, actually the search string is "ligand_types A C Cl NA OA N HD # ligand atom types" (without GPF> in the beginning). I tested your sollution it works fine but it sould added a new pattern each time before the comment # ligand atom types, after the last pattern. Now it adds it like this:  "ligand_types A C Cl NA OA N HD # ligand atom types SA"

Comment: right, I missed seeing the comments; processing them is not difficult, see the updated code

Comment: thank you it works very well! Just one question - would it be possible further customize this script to add additional lines contained the inserted keywords somewhere in the edited file? I will create a new topic for this taks showing an example..

Answer (score 2):

You could just remove any SA and/or HD that exist in the input and then always add them to the output:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    if ( match($0,/[[:space:]]*#/) ) {
        head = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) " "
        tail = substr($0,RSTART)
    }
    else {
        head = $0 " "
        tail = ""
    }
    gsub(/( (SA|HD) )|( $)/,"",head)
    print head, "SA HD" tail
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
ligand_types A C Cl NA OA N SA HD       # ligand atom types
ligand_types A C NA OA N SA HD          # ligand atom types
ligand_types A C Cl NA OA N SA HD          # ligand atom types
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`. Simple explanation would be, setting `RS` to `[[:space:]]+#` and then checking 3 conditions if current line ends with `HD` and add  `SA` to it, if current line ends with `SA` then add  `HD` to it OR if line doesn't end with both(HD and SA) then add them both and print the output in shown format by OP.

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+#' '
$0~/HD$/ && !found2{ sub(/HD$/,"& SA");found1=1 }
$0~/SA$/ && !found1{ sub(/SA$/,"& HD");found2=1 }
RT && $0!~/HD$/ && $0!~/SA$/{ $0=$0" HD SA" }
{ ORS=RT; found1=found2=""}
1
'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

GNU `sed` solution, let `file.txt` content be

```
ligand_types A C Cl NA OA N HD       # ligand atom types
ligand_types A C NA OA N SA          # ligand atom types
ligand_types A C Cl NA OA N          # ligand atom types
```

then

```
sed -e '/SA/! s/\(.*\)\([A-Z]\)/\1\2 SA/' -e '/HD/! s/\(.*\)\([A-Z]\)/\1\2 HD/' file.txt
```

gives output

```
ligand_types A C Cl NA OA N HD SA       # ligand atom types
ligand_types A C NA OA N SA HD          # ligand atom types
ligand_types A C Cl NA OA N SA HD          # ligand atom types
```

Explanation: I register 2 expressions, first is for lines which do not contain `SA`, in such case I add  `SA` after last uppercase letter. `.*` matches greedy `[A-Z]` is then last uppercase letter, as these are not to be removed I put them back in replacement using `\1` and `\2` respectively. 2nd expression does same thing but for `HD`. Note that it does add `SA` before `HD` if both are missing as stipulated by

> need to check the patterns in the string: A C Cl NA OA N SA HD

**Disclaimer**: this solution assumes that comment is always lowercase

*(tested in GNU sed 4.7)*